# How to handle exceptions from native code?

Tags: c#, exception, c++-cli

Suppose that my application is composed of 3 components. They are:

1. c++ native library
2. c++ cli managed library, which wraps native library
3. c# gui application.

As I understand, any native exception, thrown from a native c++ library will be wrapped with SEHException managed class. I am interested in the next steps, what is recommended to do after the creation of such an exception object.

Should I catch all such possible exceptions within the c++ cli managed library then create an appropriate managed exception? Something like this:

```
void some_managed_action()
{
    try
    {
       native_object->some_native_action();
    }
    catch (const NativeException& e)
    {
       // What should I do with exception e and native object? before throwing new managed exception
       // Will SEH wrapper automatically delete native exception object
       // delete all native objects?
       throw gcnew ManagedException(get_message(e));
    }
}
```

Maybe there are some pitfalls in such an approach? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There is no obvious reason to change anything in this code.  Other than the exception type name perhaps, "UnmanagedException" would make a lot more sense since that's where it came from.  Very unlikely that the C# code can do anything reasonable with it other than error reporting, the more detail you can provide the better.

Comment: @Hans Passant, As I understood, catching exception by native object is more preferable than by approp. wrapped managed one? docs says: If an unmanaged type is caught by catch(Object^), it will not destroy the thrown object.

Comment: When you write "NativeException" in your snippet then everybody will assume that is a native C++ type.  Not only is that just fine, it is *required* to get any info out of the exception object.  Passing exceptions without any relevant info at all is a very, very bad idea.  It will still work but of course your C# code can't do anything but terminate the program.  So whether or not the native exception object is leaked doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
try 
{
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // .NET exception
} 
catch 
{
    // native exception
}
```

> A catch block that handles Exception catches all Common Language
>   Specification (CLS) compliant exceptions. However, it does not catch
>   non-CLS compliant exceptions. Non-CLS compliant exceptions can be
>   thrown from native code or from managed code that was generated by the
>   Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) Assembler. Notice that the C#
>   and Visual Basic compilers do not allow non-CLS compliant exceptions
>   to be thrown and Visual Basic does not catch non-CLS compliant
>   exceptions. If the intent of the catch block is to handle all
>   exceptions, use the following general catch block syntax.
>
> C#: catch {}

[**CA2102: Catch non-CLSCompliant exceptions in general handlers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb264489.aspx)

Comment: It is good mention, I did not know, that exception raised by managed c++ should be wrapped by RuntimeWrappedException (not SEHException).

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, native code is never going to throw a managed exception.  Heaven forbid that it ever *does* happen.  Luckily the CLR will most likely treat it like a CSE (corrupted state exception) so it will never catch.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know if your comment was written to me, but from your content I think it is suppose for the op. The op probably read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404228.aspx and because of that he mentions the RuntimeWrappedException